# RVM is not a function Ubuntu/Mina/rvm

Tags: ruby, ubuntu, rvm

I've just setup an ubuntu server and need to deploy a small rails app. I'm using mina.

When I execute "mina setup", the following part of the code gives me a message(you can find it below the code) But the setup process finishes successfully.

deploy.rb

```
task :environment do
  invoke :'rvm:use[ruby-2.2.2@default]'
end
```

-

```
   $ rvm use "ruby-2.2.2@default" --create
   RVM is not a function, selecting rubies with 'rvm use ...' will not work.

   You need to change your terminal emulator preferences to allow login shell.
   Sometimes it is required to use `/bin/bash --login` as the command.
   Please visit https://rvm.io/integration/gnome-terminal/ for an example.
```

How can I get rid of this message?

I found a few similar topics but it didn't solve my problem.

**here's how I installed rvm:**

```
$ gpg --keyserver hkp://keys.gnupg.net --recv-keys 409B6B1796C275462A1703113804BB82D39DC0E3
$ curl -sSL https://get.rvm.io | sudo bash -s stable
$ sudo usermod -a -G rvm `whoami`
```

---

ps

For the setup process I used info from the following articles:

[Passenger library](https://www.phusionpassenger.com/library/walkthroughs/deploy/ruby/digital_ocean/nginx/oss/install_language_runtime.html)

[Setting Up Ruby on Rails On Digital Ocean](http://winstonyw.com/2014/10/24/setting_up_ruby_on_rails_on_digital_ocean/)

I noticed that deploy.rb from second article has .bash_profile. I dont have this file( only .profile)

```
task :environment do
  queue 'source ~/.bash_profile'

  # For those using RVM, use this to load an RVM version@gemset.
  invoke :'rvm:use[ruby-2.1.4]'
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is most probabaly because rvm is still not loaded to your bash. Load it using:

```
source ~/.rvm/scripts/rvm
```

followed by:

```
rvm use "ruby-2.2.2@default" --create
```

A permanent fix would be to add following line in your `~/.bashrc` :

```
[[ -s "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm" ]] && source "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm"
```

Comment: the first commad gives me this message: 
-bash: /home/username/.rvm/scripts/rvm: No such file or directory

Comment: is rvm installed? what is your install location?

Comment: which rvm
/usr/local/rvm/bin/rvm

Comment: Same problem(No such file or directory) I installed rvm under a different user(not root)... if it helps

Comment: I forgot to relogin after installing rvm.  I've just tried to reinstall it and I got .rvm folder in user dir.